# Does a typeclass exist for types that support the binary operators of sets

Tags: haskell, 3d, set

For background, I'm working on a [CSG (Constructive Solid Geometry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry) library.

Given polygon meshes that enclose regions of space, this library will allow those meshes to be treated as sets of the points that they enclose. And also allow the calculation of the binary operations, `union`, `intersection` and `difference`, on pairs of meshes.

The library will also support set negation.

If required I could also define an `elem` like function, with type `Point -> Mesh -> Bool`, it would not be possible to define an `add` function, as there exists no meaningful way to add a single point to a mesh.

Does a typeclass exist for types that support these operations? 
And if not, what would a good implementation of a suitable typeclass look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people have tried making unifying typeclasses for container types, and none of them has ever caught on, each for its own reasons. I recommend not bothering; the current standard idiom is to just define the operations for your new type with some standardish names, not worrying about name clashes, with whatever type makes the most sense for your new container. Expect users to import your module qualified and aliased to avoid name clashes (and aid readers as a nice side effect).

Comment: The type in question isn't a container per say, as it's not possible to add discreet points to it. I'll also argue that there is value to having a typeclass here, as the same operations are possible on regions of 2d (or N dimensional) space.

Comment: I'm accepting this, since it's good advise, and nothing more specific seems to be forthcoming